# Product Rule of Counting Strategies Question

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

I have been struggling on this question. I don't understand how I could work out how to find out what the four key code consisted of.

Question:

The diagram shows keypads for four different types of alarm.

Each keypad has a four-key code.

Premier alarm Keypad

1 2 3 4 5

6 7 8 9 0

A B C

How many different codes possible for the

Premier alarm keypad?

What I did:
$$10 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3
= 810,000$$

I don't understand how to approach this question as I don't understand the combinations of digits and letters that should be in the four key code.

Thank You and Help is Appreciated

Comment: The way I read this the keypad has $13$ characters.  If that is the case, how many ways can you choose each position in your four-key code?

Comment: I don't understand that

Comment: You have $13$ choices for each of the four entries.  How many four-key codes can you form?

Comment: 13 * 13 * 13 * 13 = 28 561

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: Thank You for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keypad has $13$ characters.  To form a code, we must form a sequence of length $4$ using those characters.  We have $13$ choices for each entry, so the number of such sequences is $13^4$, as you found.